# APK Deployment Issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have been able to create a *.apk file from my code, place the file
in IIS, and download it onto a number of Android phones. Upon the
install, the application works exactly as expected.

However, after a phone is rebooted, the application name is changed to
the fully-qualified Java class name of the activity in the menu (so
"MyActivity" becomes "com.mycompany.MyActivity"), and when I try to go
to Menu > Settings, I get an error that causes android to force close
my application.

Looking into DDMS, I see that I get an error indicating that it can
not find my Preferences activity, despite the fact upon initial
install, it works properly.

I'm using Eclipse on Windows XP, and have several Android devices at
my disposal to test with.

Any idea what's going on?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.company.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name"> <!--android:debuggable="true">-->
    <activity android:name="com.company.app.ActivityMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.company.app.Preferences"
              android:label="@string/app_settings">
              <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE"></category>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
              </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.company.app.Service"></service>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your manifest? Also, has this happened on a variety of phones, or did you only try one (and if so, which phone)? Also, is "Menu > Settings" something in your app?

Comment: What does application info (Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> your app) say before and after rebooting ?

Comment: I've edited my question to include my manifest. I've been working mainly with the HTC Hero, but have tried it on a couple of devices (HTC Droid Eris or HTC Tattoo). The Menu > Settings is my menu option to open my Preferences activity. Before reboot, the Settings > Applications > Manage Applications lists my app as the value for string/app_name. After reboot, it reads com.company.app.

Comment: Okay, so a quick update.  I compiled the famous notepad example program and deployed using the same process that I've been using to deploy my own application, and everything works as expected.  This leads me to believe that it is something in my code or manifest, and not my environment.

Comment: Another update. The HelloActivity example from the SDK download exhibits the same behavior as my application.  If I install it, everything is fine, however on a reboot, the name of the application changes to the package name. I've also noticed that in the Google examples, they do not place a period before their class names in the androidmanifest.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got this to work. I think that the package installer on the HTC Hero (and maybe the HTC Droid Eris) has some issues.

I uninstalled my application from the phone, changed the name of my main activity, and re-deployed it onto the Hero.  I started to immediately get a "Force Close."  I connected the device to DDMS and looked at the error.  It was still looking for my old activity name.  I factory reset the device and reinstalled the same package (with the updated name) and everything works as expected.

So it seems that the package installer is caching some part of the old manifest or something, not really sure what exactly is going on there.  I may play with it some more if I get time.

I don't know if someone else could verify this problem, maybe it's something that should be taken up with HTC?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.company.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name"> <!--android:debuggable="true">-->
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences"
              android:label="@string/app_settings">
              <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE"></category>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
              </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Service"></service>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This resulted in the same behavior that I was seeing before.  I don't think qualifying the names differently is the issue.  After doing some more playing around (by creating a separate test project), it seems that everything is fine until I add another activity.  Perhaps how I'm declaring these Activities is incorrect?